# Como usar a anotação Foreign Key no C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataannotations

Sou **leigo** e gostaria muito de **aprender** sobre.

Vou usar no exemplo **Model A** e **B** para não ficar confuso:

Eu vi sobre a **Model A** ter a anotação `Foreign Key` na `prop virtual Model B virModelB` referenciando uma `prop int ModelBID` para armazenar o dado.

E na **Model B** ter uma `prop virtual ICollection<ModelA> virModelA`, porém eu não entendi como que uma Model está "enxergando" a outra... 
Existe alguma diferença de se fazer a Model para cada relacionamento (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many)?

Resumindo:

- Contruir cada Model

  - Foreign Key Annotation
  - ICollection<>
- Relacionamentos

  - One-to-one
  - One-to-many
  - Many-to-many

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim Sim, eu faço de outra forma e comecei a estudar isso porque acho que fica mais organizado e tal... Dai eu queria um exemplo com explicações para ter um modelo para sanar minhas duvidas. Porque os que tenho visto pela net, sempre fica alguma duvida pendente e eu acredito que aqui, vocês conseguem me ajudar... :)

Comment: Creio que esse link poderá te ajudar muito em várias coisas sobre o Entity Framework. Qualquer dúvida que surgir entre em contato conosco. No momento está meio difícil de elaborar uma boa resposta para você, mas se ninguém responder, mais tarde eu elaboro e posto aqui. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Muito obrigado @PedroPaulo! Eu criei um post sobre o problema que eu estava tendo, mas eu vi que ninguem conseguiu me ajudar e foi ai que decidi criar este, sendo mais teorico, para expandir meu conhecimento para que assim eu consiga sozinho resolver o meu problema. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793570/models-join-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente o `DataAnnotations [ForeignKey]` é apenas para explicitar o campo de chave estrangeira em relacionamentos entre duas entidades, por exemplo:

```
public class Livro
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public int AutorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AutorId")]
    public virtual Autor { get; set; }
}

public class Autor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

No exemplo citado acima temos uma classe Livro e uma classe Autor, este é um relacionamento One-To-Many de `Autor` para `Livro`, pois um autor pode ter vários livros, mais um livro tem apenas um autor. Usamos a anotação `[ForeignKey("AutorId")]` para explicitar ao EFCore que a nossa chave estrangeira que referencia o livro para o autor é `AutorId`. Nós também poderiamos fazer o relacionamento sem explicitar ao EFCore qual campo será a chave, fazendo com que o próprio EF Core crie um campo gerado automaticamente para realizar a chave, neste caso nem precisaríamos criar campo `AutorId`na classe Livro conforme abaixo:

```
public class Livro
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public virtual Autor { get; set; }
}

public class Autor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
}
```

Os dois exemplos acima retratam a mesma estrutura de classe, a diferença é que no segundo exemplo quem irá gerar a chave estrangeira é o próprio EF Core. O que irá gerar a seguinte estrutura de tabelas (Usarei o SQL como base):

```
CREATE TABLE Livro(
   Id INT NOT NULL,
   Nome NVARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Autor(
   Id INT NOT NULL,
   Titulo NVARCHAR,
   AutorId INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (AutorId) REFERENCES Livro (Id)
   PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

*OBS.: Pode ser que a estrutura das tabelas tenha alguma diferença quanto a esta, mais deve se aproximar ao descrito acima.*

EFCore fomenta o uso de mapeamento fluente sem a utlização de DataAnnotations, por isso na documentação oficial da [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/relational/fk-constraints) ou do [EFCore](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx), provavelmente você não vai encontrar referencia ao uso de DataAnnotations. Porém você encontrará mais detalhes do uso de DataAnnotations na [documentação do EntityFramework 6 Code First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado!! Só uma ultima abusada no seu tempo, conseguiria me mostrar o many-to-many? É um dos meus maiores problemas...

Comment: de uma olhada neste [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) @LeoHenrique

Comment: Eu tentei fazer o exemplo do link, mas esse item `DbModelBuilder`, nao é encontrado nunca pelo meu VS, eu nao sei se é pq o meu VS é o 2013 e dai nao tem a assembly necessaria... Mas td bem, eu nao conhecia esse site que varios de vcs me mandaram e gostei bastante, agora é so me aprofundar... Obrigado a todos os envolvidos!

Comment: @LeoHenrique, provavelmente está faltando alguma referência na sua aplicação para não reconhecer o DbModelBuilder, pois o mesmo é membro do DbContext. Ou pode ser a versão que você está usando, você consegue dizer se á EF Core, ou se é EntityFramework 6 ?

Comment: uso o EntityFramework 6.2.0

Comment: Então, o link que o João Paulo postou é do EF Core, o link para o EntityFramework 6 é esse: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx mais esse não é o problema, pois as duas versões utilizam o mesmo objeto (DbModelBuilder), provavelmente a sua aplicação está sem a referencia do System.Data.Entity ou alguma outra referência necessária para o EntityFramework

Comment: Estou usando isso `System.Data.Entity`, mesmo pq eu uso o `DbContext`, acho q falta alguma outra referencia, mas não sei saber qual...